# ASP.NET Page Double Event Firing

Tags: asp.net, session, postback, double, state

Details:

- Page has asynch true
- Double event does not fire every time.
- Page has a long running process. The double event can be simulated with a thread.sleep()
- Steps have been taken to prevent double post back. The second event often will fire 10 or 20 minutes after the first event.
- May not happen on development server
- Site is running on 2 servers with load balancer
- Page is in an admin directory

Thoughts:

- May have something to do with session
- A bug in firefox on close tab?
- Something to do with Asynch property?
- Process is not completing and restarting?

I don't use any AJAX. The page has "asynch=true" and generates the double postback/event.

The only code required to duplicate is a thread.sleep timer and some way to register postbacks. This page is protected.

My 2 strongest hypothesis:

Firefox is causing the postback on a tab close. Why? 
Session state is dieing

Comment: Show us the code in question. Otherwise answers will be pure speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the history feature in Ajax?

I remember having a similar double postback problem last year when the page posted back a second time after the initial post back. This second post back was the result of the Ajax code firing another postback behind the scenes to ensure that the history list is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any AJAX. The page has "asynch=true" and generates the double postback/event.

The only code required to duplicate is a thread.sleep timer and some way to register postbacks. This page is protected.

My 2 strongest hypothesis:

1. Firefox is causing the postback on a tab close. Why?
2. Session state is dieing

Comment: This "answer" should instead be a modification to your question. I've modified your question by adding this information.  Ideally, you should delete this answer.